# Determinating direction of profile graph

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 3d-analyst

I'm creating profile graph for craters. Each of polylines was created same way:

1. bearing distance to line in two opposite direction from crater's center, for example with bearing angle 30° and 210°
2. merging together each pair of lines
3. dissolve each pair
4. interpolate them with DEM

Now I have 8 polylines through each crater center. Lets say, now I want to create profile graphs. But can I be sure that graph was created from "left" to "right", not from "right" to "left"? (on screenshot) I don't have time and resourses to manually check each graph and compare it with DTM. My created polylines only have X and Y coords of center of crater. I do know though value of bearings of each profile.

So, I need to know direction of created profile graphs. Maybe there is a basic algorithm for arcmap to create them, like "start from top left then to bottom right"?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Add Geometry Attributes](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm) tool on your line dataset to compute line bearing. As this always computes the bearing starting from the FROM end of the line you can determine which direction it is going. Select those and run the [Flip line](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/flip-line.htm) tool.

This could all easily be wrapped up in a simple model.

This approach does assume you have at least a standard license.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed. But I'm confused with bearing a bit, english not my first language and there's weird description. If bearing is 0, it means line starts south, ends north?

Comment: Reading the help file I would understand a zero would mean it started from the south and went directly north, easy to check?

Comment: Yep exactly. A bit weird wording.